# Find elements where text contains entries from a list/array

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, tampermonkey

I'm working on a custom user script that will block/mark users from my list. Say the list will contain strings "EvilJoe", "ToxicWill" & "NegativeSara". I want to find all, say, "span.username" elements where text inside the span contains one of the strings above, so for example "User EvilJoe Premium" would match.

I can do it with a loop through badUserNames, where for each badUserNameI'd do something like

```
 $("span.username:contains(badUserName)").append(" - bad guy");
```

Is this an effective solution though?

Comment: What do you mean with "effective"? Did you have any problems?

Comment: @trincot say requiring the least amount of code keeping the performance of more wordy solutions. Can it be done in 1 line, without worsening the performance compared to my simple solution?

Answer (score 0):

**:contains** will be slow if there is a large number of DOM elements because the jQuery itself acting as a middle to translate the **:contains** to a native JS function. in that case it is better to use a regular expression like this:

```
var badUserRegex = new RegExp('(EvilJoe|ToxicWill|NegativeSara)', 'i');

// Find all the span.username elements that match the regex
$('span.username').filter(function() {
  return badUserRegex.test($(this).text());
}).append(' - bad guy');
```

Answer (score 0):

This code searches the entire body of the page for elements that contain any of the search terms in the `searchTerms` array. The `:not(script)` selector is used to exclude any script elements from the search.

#### Try below Code

```js
var searchTerms = ["badUserName"];
var matchingElements = $("body :not(script)").filter(function () {
  var elementText = $(this).clone().children().remove().end().text();
  return searchTerms.some(function (term) {
    return elementText.indexOf(term) > -1;
  });
});
matchingElements.append(" - bad guy");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div>
    <p>Text content badUserName.</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Text content badUserName between</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>badUserName text at starts.</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>no text.</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

You can modify this code as per you want